# Compute cross entropy loss for classification in pytorch

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, pytorch

I am trying to build two neural network for classification. One for Binary and the second is for multi-class classification. I am trying to use the `torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss()` as a loss function, but I try to train my first neural network I get the following error:

```
multi-target not supported at /opt/conda/conda-bld/pytorch_1565272271120/work/aten/src/THNN/generic/ClassNLLCriterion.c:22
```

From my analysis, I found that the my dataset has two problems that caused the error.

- **My data set is one hot encoded**. I used one hot encoding to pre processes my dataset. The first target `Y_binary` variable has the shape of `torch.Size([125973, 1])` full of 0s and 1 indicating classes 'No' and 'Yes'.
- **My data has the wrong dimensions?** I found that I can't use a simple vector with the cross entropy loss function. Some people used the following code to reshape their target vector before feeding to the loss function.

`out = out.permute(0, 2, 3, 1).contiguous().view(-1, class_number)`

But I didn't really understand the reasoning behind this code. But it seems for my that I need to keep track of the following variables: `Class_Number`, `Batch_size`, `Dimension_Output`. For my code here are the dimensions

```
X_train.shape: (125973, 122)
Y_train2.shape: (125973, 1)
batch_size = 64
K = len(set(Y_train2)) # Binary classification For multi class classification use K = len(set(Y_train5))
```

- Should the target value be one hot encoded? If not, how I can feed a nominal feature to the loss function?
- If I use reshape the output, can you help me do this for my code ?

I am trying to use this loss function for both my neural networks.

Thank you in advance,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is due to the usage of [torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss()](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html?highlight=crossentropyloss#torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss) which can be used if you want to predict 1 class out of N classes. For multiclass classification, you should use [torch.nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss()](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#torch.nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss) which combines a [Sigmoid](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html?highlight=sigmoid#torch.nn.Sigmoid) layer and the [BCELoss](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html?highlight=bceloss#torch.nn.BCELoss) in one single class.

In case of multi-class, and if you use Sigmoid + BCELoss, then you need the target to be one-hot encoding, i.e. something like this per sample: `[0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0]`, where 1 will be at the locations of classes present.

Comment: So how can I solve the error? Can the  torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss() be used in a binary classification? I didn't fully understand your answer.

Comment: Use CrossEntropyLoss if examples are associated with only one class, otherwise, use BCEWithLogitsLoss (whenever you have examples with multiple class labels).